# telnet pull data timeout issue

Tags: ruby, timeout, telnet

This is the data I get through normal telnet or even through ruby telnet.  I am not sure how to tell it to quit when it gets to `END DATABASE`

```
# Manual telnet method
Trying 10.1.1.12...
Connected to 10.1.1.12.
Escape character is '^]'.
F#1=
F#1=
BEGIN DATABASE

2011-12-29 13:53,1,Hefer Meal,240,247,Z88,1,1
2011-12-29 13:53,1,Vegetable Oil,30,59,Z88,1,1
2011-12-29 13:55,2,Vegetable Oil,100,106,530,1,1
2011-12-29 13:55,2,Steer Meal,800,809,530,1,1
2011-12-29 13:56,3,Vegetable Oil,150,153,530,1,0
2011-12-29 13:57,3,Steer Meal,1200,1203,530,1,0
2011-12-29 14:30,4,Vegetable Oil,17,18,210,1,1
2011-12-29 14:31,4,Liquid Starter,388,394,210,1,1
2011-12-29 14:39,5,Hefer Meal,1200,1227,Z88,1,2
2011-12-29 14:40,6,Hefer Meal,1200,1240,Z88,1,2
2011-12-29 14:41,7,Hefer Meal,1200,1207,Z88,1,0
2011-12-29 14:43,8,Hefer Meal,1200,1286,Z88,1,2
2011-12-29 14:46,9,Vegetable Oil,115,122,530,1,1
2011-12-29 14:50,9,Steer Meal,920,950,530,1,1
2011-12-29 14:56,10,Vegetable Oil,47,48,312,1,0
2011-12-29 14:57,10,Steer Meal,237,261,312,1,1
2011-12-29 14:58,10,Liquid Starter,389,394,312,1,1
END DATABASE
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require 'net/telnet'
localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "10.1.1.12", "Timeout" => 10, "Port" => 10001) { |resp| print "===> " + resp }
localhost.cmd("F#1=") do |data| 
   print data
end
```

When this runs it outputs all the data then waits and errors with:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/telnet.rb:557:in `waitfor': timed out while waiting for more data (Timeout::Error)
```

I am honestly not even sure where to go from here, I have looked at [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html) page for more info on how to deal with it, but I can't find anything.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using a non standard telnet server here. Please set "Telnetmode" to false when initializing.

```
localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "10.1.1.12", "Telnetmode" => false, "Timeout" => 10, "Port" => 10001) { |resp| print "===> " + resp }
```

Comment: I still get the same error with the code you provided.  Thank you for your help, and I would appreciate any other suggestions you may have.

Comment: made the vendor change the way the telnet worked, then your code helped me out.  Thank you.